# How to style menu?

Tags: asp.net

I have a dynamic menu with all inline style.
  I want to give some spacing before the menu item text on left side. If giving padding left style to DynamicMenuStyle then whole cell affected not text inside cell. How to do it??

please reply...

Regards
Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define an style like this

```
    .WithPadding{
        padding-left:5px;
    }
```

and add

```
    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="WithPadding" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to give extra spacing before the text then padding is the right way. But when applying padding you have to take into consideration the width of the container also. When applying padding the total width of the container might change.